# Django: undefined template variable renders as context dump

Tags: python, django, templates

Django 1.10.1

My template is using a mandatory 'title' context variable and an optional 'note' template variable.

Rendering {{ title }} works fine, but rendering {{ note }} causes a full template context to be rendered (kind of debug view?) if note is not defined in the context.

I would expect that is 'note' is not defined in the context it would render an empty string, and if defined renders the content of the variable.

**Example:**

urls.py:

```
url(r'^test1', views.testview1),
url(r'^test2', views.testview2),
```

views.py:

```
def testview1(request):
    context = {'title': 'My title', 'note': 'my note'}
    return render(request, 'test_template.html', context)


def testview2(request):
    context = {'title': 'My title'}
    return render(request, 'test_template.html', context)
```

test_template.html:

```
<h2>{{ title }}</h2>
{{ note }}
```

testview1 renders as expected:

> ### My title
>
> my note

testview2 renders this unexpected context dump:

> ### My title
>
> [{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, 
>   {u'csrf_token': < SimpleLazyObject: u'ho7MGwEQ86eMVLmHZbDPYE8VLCo3aTAUTM0OAf7Pvr5E8exMKYDqNoTjQGmieLPu'>, 
>   'user': < SimpleLazyObject: < User: user1>>, 
>   'perms': < django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x113826f50>, 
>   'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'INFO': 20, 'WARNING': 30, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'ERROR': 40}, 
>   'messages': < django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x11376b550>, 
>   u'request': < WSGIRequest: GET '/swingit/test2'>}, {}, {'title': 'My title'}]

This is the settings.py context related to templates:

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'allauth')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'string_if_invalid': '',
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

These python modules are in the virtual environment:

```
Babel==2.3.4
BulkSMS==0.3
cGraph==0.1
diff-match-patch==20121119
Django==1.10.1
django-allauth==0.27.0
django-bootstrap-ui==0.2.0
django-bootstrap3==7.0.1
django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.5
django-extensions==1.7.4
django-import-export==0.5.1
django-mailjet==0.2.0
django-phonenumber-field==1.1.0
django-tag-parser==2.1
django-utils==0.0.2
dominate==2.1.17
funcsigs==1.0.2
graphviz==0.5.1
mailjet-rest==1.2.2
MarkupSafe==0.23
mock==2.0.0
nose==1.3.7
oauthlib==2.0.0
pbr==1.10.0
phonenumberslite==7.7.2
pydot2==1.0.33
pygraphviz==1.3.1
pyparsing==2.1.10
python-openid==2.2.5
pytz==2016.7
requests==2.11.1
requests-oauthlib==0.6.2
six==1.10.0
sqlparse==0.2.1
tablib==0.11.2
```

Comment: Disabled all applications one by one, none of them caused this issue. When I create a new django project this issue is not present, so clearly my project has some misconfiguration somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

One of the python packages had a local change.

So this solved this problem:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed
```